# QuartzCore - CA::Render::Shmem::new_shmen() memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks, quartz-core

I find out QuartzCore - CA::Render::Shmem::new_shmen()craete somthing and never release and cause memory leak.

This repeats many times and so my memory allocation increase gradually.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because some of my object (mainly viewcontroller) is not realeased.
If you have this problem, check weather your stuff is released or not.